# Django ORM not working for models

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've a model Product and it has a sub model Variation for product variations. Now I am trying to add a Shop Model top of Products and I wish to get products listed uploaded by the Shop owner who created the shop. But I am getting an error. Following is my code:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    description = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    categories = models.ManyToManyField('Category', blank=True)
    default = models.ForeignKey('Category', related_name='default_category', null=True, blank=True)
    hits = models.ManyToManyField(HitCount, blank=True)
    hitcounts = GenericRelation(HitCount, content_type_field='content_type', object_id_field='object_pk',)


    objects = ProductManager()

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-title"]

class Variation(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20)
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=20, null=True, blank=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    inventory = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True) #refer none == unlimited amount

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title

class Shop(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=False, blank=False)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(Product)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=image_upload_to_shop, null=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=120)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

Error I am getting is when I try to add shop:

```
Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/admin/products/shop/add/

Django Version: 1.8.5
Python Version: 2.7.9
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'blog',
 'products',
 'orders',
 'carts',
 'newsletter',
 'crispy_forms',
 'registration',
 'colorfield',
 'hitcount')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in wrapper
  616.                 return self.admin_site.admin_view(view)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  57.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\sites.py" in inner
  233.             return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in add_view
  1516.         return self.changeform_view(request, None, form_url, extra_context)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapper
  34.             return bound_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  110.                     response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in bound_func
  30.                 return func.__get__(self, type(self))(*args2, **kwargs2)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\utils\decorators.py" in inner
  145.                     return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in changeform_view
  1468.                 self.save_related(request, form, formsets, not add)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\options.py" in save_related
  1100.         form.save_m2m()
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\forms\models.py" in save_m2m
  102.                 f.save_form_data(instance, cleaned_data[f.name])
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in save_form_data
  2590.         setattr(instance, self.attname, data)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in __set__
  1261.             manager.clear()
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related.py" in clear
  998.                 self.through._default_manager.using(db).filter(filters).delete()
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in delete
  537.         collector.delete()
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\deletion.py" in delete
  292.                 qs._raw_delete(using=self.using)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _raw_delete
  549.         sql.DeleteQuery(self.model).delete_qs(self, using)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\subqueries.py" in delete_qs
  78.         self.get_compiler(using).execute_sql(NO_RESULTS)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py" in execute_sql
  840.             cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  79.             return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py" in __exit__
  97.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py" in execute
  64.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\Shazia\ecommerce\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\base.py" in execute
  318.         return Database.Cursor.execute(self, query, params)

Exception Type: OperationalError at /admin/products/shop/add/
Exception Value: no such table: products_shop_products
```

Here is my migration table for my apps:

001-Initial.py

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import migrations, models
import colorfield.fields
import products.models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('hitcount', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Category',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=120)),
                ('slug', models.SlugField(unique=True)),
                ('description', models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('timestamp', models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='color_product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('color', colorfield.fields.ColorField(default=b'#FF0000', max_length=10)),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('description', models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('categories', models.ManyToManyField(to='products.Category', blank=True)),
                ('default', models.ForeignKey(related_name='default_category', blank=True, to='products.Category', null=True)),
                ('hits', models.ManyToManyField(to='hitcount.HitCount', blank=True)),
            ],
            options={
                'ordering': ['-title'],
            },
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ProductFeatured',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to=products.models.image_upload_to_featured)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)),
                ('text', models.CharField(max_length=220, null=True, blank=True)),
                ('text_right', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('text_css_color', models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)),
                ('show_price', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('make_image_background', models.BooleanField(default=False)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='ProductImage',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('image', models.ImageField(upload_to=products.models.image_upload_to)),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Shop',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('name', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('image', models.ImageField(null=True, upload_to=products.models.image_upload_to_shop)),
                ('location', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('products', models.ManyToManyField(to='products.Product')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='size_product',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('size', models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=[(b'XS', b'XS'), (b'S', b'S'), (b'SM', b'SM'), (b'M', b'M'), (b'L', b'L'), (b'XL', b'Xl'), (b'XXL', b'XXL')])),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.CreateModel(
            name='Variation',
            fields=[
                ('id', models.AutoField(verbose_name='ID', serialize=False, auto_created=True, primary_key=True)),
                ('title', models.CharField(max_length=120)),
                ('price', models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=2)),
                ('sale_price', models.DecimalField(null=True, max_digits=20, decimal_places=2, blank=True)),
                ('active', models.BooleanField(default=True)),
                ('inventory', models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)),
                ('product', models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product')),
            ],
        ),
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='color_product',
            name='product',
            field=models.ForeignKey(to='products.Product'),
        ),
    ]
```

002_shop_user.py

```
class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        migrations.swappable_dependency(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
        ('products', '0001_initial'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='shop',
            name='user',
            field=models.ForeignKey(default=1, to=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL),
            preserve_default=False,
        ),
    ]
```

Comment: You did not migrate the database.

Comment: The error is clear, the intermediate table does not exist. Have you run makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: run commands `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate`

Comment: I did migrated and repeated just now again. In fact I've deleted all my migrations and db as I am working with development server. Error won't go away.

Comment: Then please show the output of running those commands, and the code of the migrations themselves.

Comment: @Daniel I've added my migration results instead in my original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is strange but once I deleted all my migrations and db again...it worked. Thank you for help.